# Why vdots and ddots are square dots, while cdots are round dots (in Beamer)?

Tags: beamer, math-mode

I was writing some mathematical equations in Beamer and I noticed something strange.

The outcome of the following code, using the standalone class, seems perfect.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$
\psi(\vec{x_1},\dotsc,\vec{x}_N) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N!}} \begin{vmatrix} \chi_1(\vec{x}_1) & \cdots & \chi_N(\vec{x}_1) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\  \chi_1(\vec{x}_N) & \cdots & \chi_N(\vec{x}_N)\end{vmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

However, the exactly same code within the Beamer class, produces cubic dots with the commands `vdots` and `ddots`, instead of round dots as in the previous example (using `standalone`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
$
\psi(\vec{x_1},\dotsc,\vec{x}_N) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N!}} \begin{vmatrix} \chi_1(\vec{x}_1) & \cdots & \chi_N(\vec{x}_1) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\  \chi_1(\vec{x}_N) & \cdots & \chi_N(\vec{x}_N)\end{vmatrix}
$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Why we have this behaviour? How can I fix it?

Comment: The dots used in `\vdots` and `\ddots` are taken from the text font, which is a square dot in sans serif, whereas the dots in `\dotsc` are from the mathfont (`\ldotp` to be precise) which is round.

Comment: @HenriMenke, I believe that qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interesting difference ... It can be corrected with the help of the `mathdots` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools,mathdots}

    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$
\psi(\vec{x_1},\dotsc,\vec{x}_N) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N!}} \begin{vmatrix} \chi_1(\vec{x}_1) & \dotsm & \chi_N(\vec{x}_1) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\  \chi_1(\vec{x}_N) & \cdots & \chi_N(\vec{x}_N)\end{vmatrix}
$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:** Shape of dots depends on font shape. For example, `iwona` fonts don't need `mathdots` for rounded dots:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
   \usepackage[math]{iwona}
   \SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{iwona}{OT1}{\ttdefault}{m}{n}

    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
\psi(\vec{x_1},\dotsc,\vec{x}_N) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N!}} \begin{vmatrix} \chi_1(\vec{x}_1) & \dotsm & \chi_N(\vec{x}_1) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\  \chi_1(\vec{x}_N) & \cdots & \chi_N(\vec{x}_N)\end{vmatrix}
\]
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

gives similar result as the first MWE.

**Edit:** Also, if you select in the first case (width `standalone` document class) `sffamily`, you will get the same result as with `beamer`.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
    \sffamily
\[
\psi(\vec{x_1},\dotsc,\vec{x}_N) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N!}} \begin{vmatrix} \chi_1(\vec{x}_1) & \cdots & \chi_N(\vec{x}_1) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\  \chi_1(\vec{x}_N) & \cdots & \chi_N(\vec{x}_N)\end{vmatrix}
\]
    \end{document}
```

In other words: *the shape of dots depends on font type and font shape and not on document class*. You observe differences because `beamer` default fonts use sans serif font shape.